# How to run javadoc from Windows 10?

Tags: java, javadoc

Beginner here.  I've just downloaded the Java JDK, the left large button at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html and installed.  Java is running, I've run it from the command line.  I'd like to run javadoc without typing its full path name.  But even when I do that, probably because there is a space in c:\Program Files\java.... it's not able to be found by Windows.  How can I just run javadoc from the command line?

Also, why I have you, why does java run from the command line and javadoc doesn't?  They are both in the same directory.

Windows error message at the command line.

> javadoc /?
>   'javadoc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

UPDATE: Geany (which is a light Java editor) can't find javac either.  This is probably related to the above problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javadoc Compilation

To generate the html documentation, run Javadoc followed by the list of source files, which the documentation is to be generated for, in the command prompt (i.e. Javadoc [files]).
Javadoc also provides additional options which can be entered as switches following the Javadoc command (i.e. Javadoc [options] [files]).
Here are some basic Javadoc options:

```
-author - generated documentation will include a author section
-classpath [path] - specifies path to search for referenced .class files.
-classpathlist [path];[path];...;[path] - specifies a list locations (separated by ";") to search for referenced .class files.
-d [path] - specifies where generated documentation will be saved.
-private - generated documentation will include private fields and methods (only public and protected ones are included by default).
-sourcepath [path] - specifies path to search for .java files to generate documentation form.
-sourcepathlist [path];[path];...;[path] - specifies a list locations (separated by ";") to search for .java files to generate documentation form.
-version - generated documentation will include a version section
```

To answer your question:

```
Javadoc [options] [files]
Javadoc java_file_name.java
```

Make sure you have a [system variable created for JAVA_HOME](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-on-windows-10/) for it to work.

Comment: Yes, thanks, it was the environment variables, haven't fiddled with them since about XP days.

Answer (score 1):

The Java installer adds the directory `"c:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath"` to the `PATH` environment variable. That directory contains four executables: `java.exe`, `javaw.exe`, `javac.exe`, and `jshell.exe`. The other tools of the Java Development Kit are in a different directory, such as `"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin"`. You can provide the complete path `"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\javadoc"`, or you can add that directory to the `PATH` environment variable.